# Deleting Items from Listbox - Runtime Error 381

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and have been hacking together code from various examples and tutorials around the web. I'm aware that this will mean my code is hideous and inefficient, but I'm focusing on getting things to work right now and learning to clean up later.

I'm stuck on the part of my task that involves making an 'address manager' to store modifiable lists of recipients for daily email tasks. I created a userform to act as the manager, and it works fine to add files (user fills in textbox and clicks add, item is added to listbox and to relevant sheet in the workbook) and deletion works fine to a point (user selects item from listbox, clicks delete, item is removed from listbox and source sheet, and the list is repopulated.)

I can add and delete items freely, and the rest of my program interacts properly with the lists, but for some reason there's a weird problem I can't find the source of. When I created the file to test, I added 2 email addresses to each tab that contains a recipient list. I can add recipients and they show up perfectly, and I can also delete them without issue. The problem occurs when I try to delete one of the last two entries (regardless of what they are) I will get a Runtime Error 381 - Invalid Property Array index.

The debugger points me right at the starred part of the following code, which is the code I use to populate the list. It works fine as long as there are more than 2 entries for each. As soon as one of the last two entries are removed, the runtime error occurs and I can't even open the userform unless I go and manually add a second entry to the source sheet. I'm sure I`m missing something simple, but I really appreciate any help you may have.

```
Sub FillFS4ListBox()
     Dim rng As Range
     Me.MultiPage1(0).FS4listbox.Clear
     With wb.Sheets("FS4")
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
         **Me.MultiPage1(0).FS4listbox.List = rng.Value**
     End With
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Me.MultiPage1(0).FS4listbox.List = rng.Value
```

Using `Value` on a single-cell range doesn't produce an array, just a single value.  If `List` expects an array then you'll need to check your input range to see if it's a single cell, then wrap that cell's value using (eg) `Array()`

E.g. - putting this in a function:

```
Function GetList(rng As Range)
    GetList = IIf(rng.Count = 1, Array(rng.Value), rng.Value)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Me.MultiPage1(0).FS4listbox.List = GetList(rng)
```